# SQL Update - not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a problem and I do not understand why it is not working. I just want to update a few specific entries inside my database. The problem is that right now the countries are in English inside the database so I want to rename all English countries with German country names.

Here is a screenshot of the tables inside my SQL database:
[image]

Now here is the SQL Code I am using to update the database:

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value`=Tschechien WHERE `meta_value`=Czech Republic
```

And here is the error message I receive:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Republic' at line 1

Now I tried a different country which you can see here:

[image]

And I used this code:

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value`=Deutschland WHERE `meta_value`=Germany
```

And I get this error message:

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'Germany' in 'where clause'

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? The table is called "wp_usermeta". I really hope that someone can help me and let me know why my update code is not working.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, you need quotes around the values.  The database thinks you are trying to update using a column called "Germany" and "Czech", and does not understand the keyword "Republic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put single or double quotes around Germany:

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value`=Deutschland WHERE `meta_value`= "Germany"
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this...

```
 WHERE `meta_value`='Czech Republic'
```

because your country names are handled as text strings.